# Creating a data.frame from 3 matrices

Tags: r, matrix

I have following data and code:

DATA:

```
> ddf
           vnum1      vnum2 vint1 vint2 vyear
1   0.3878784349 0.61856052     3     9  2013
2  -0.1715074407 0.53045776     8     4  2014
3  -0.5835102451 0.06261218     7     6  2009
4  -0.0001529602 0.52475223     9     4  2012
5  -0.3788561360 0.73767935     7     8  2011
6   0.4655585989 0.35300322     3    11  2013
7   0.6647057814 0.53344731     5     7  2014
8   1.1537467543 0.83244251     6     7  2012
9   2.7525645298 0.66707480     1     9  2009
10  0.9063236184 0.89991709    10     4  2014
11 -1.2079772974 0.83952909     4     3  2013
12 -0.9229426008 0.59305684     9     3  2010
13 -0.9189135265 0.67158655     4     9  2011
14  0.0171407600 0.21849402     6     6  2012
15  0.3238003823 0.72707166     1     2  2012
16  0.7023232273 0.10858232    10     3  2013
17  1.8774988873 0.66128645     8     4  2011
18 -1.0178875266 0.10277654     3    12  2014
19 -1.5038029776 0.74933385     2    11  2011
20 -2.2545370826 0.52037556     7     1  2013
21 -0.5070672623 0.70556583    10    11  2012
22  0.5332096642 0.05624691     2     4  2009
23 -0.1016724979 0.30406996     3     8  2010
24  1.6554541496 0.24258070    10     5  2011
25 -1.8601185335 0.34306609     7     6  2010
> 
> dput(ddf)
structure(list(vnum1 = c(0.387878434882536, -0.171507440740263, 
-0.583510245133433, -0.000152960203773939, -0.378856135972161, 
0.465558598897948, 0.664705781421418, 1.15374675427851, 2.75256452978797, 
0.90632361837742, -1.20797729742402, -0.922942600847586, -0.918913526542506, 
0.0171407600378223, 0.323800382345413, 0.702323227252284, 1.87749888731167, 
-1.01788752655329, -1.50380297756717, -2.25453708258335, -0.507067262341542, 
0.53320966418502, -0.101672497856537, 1.65545414961551, -1.86011853354809
), vnum2 = c(0.618560523493215, 0.530457757413387, 0.062612181995064, 
0.524752234807238, 0.737679345766082, 0.353003220865503, 0.533447309629992, 
0.832442505517974, 0.667074795579538, 0.899917090777308, 0.839529090793803, 
0.593056835001335, 0.67158655426465, 0.218494015280157, 0.727071655681357, 
0.108582322485745, 0.661286452319473, 0.102776538114995, 0.749333853134885, 
0.520375560736284, 0.705565832322463, 0.056246911874041, 0.304069962818176, 
0.242580699035898, 0.343066089553759), vint1 = c(3L, 8L, 7L, 
9L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 10L, 4L, 9L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 10L, 8L, 3L, 
2L, 7L, 10L, 2L, 3L, 10L, 7L), vint2 = c(9L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 8L, 
11L, 7L, 7L, 9L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 9L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 12L, 11L, 1L, 
11L, 4L, 8L, 5L, 6L), vyear = c(2013L, 2014L, 2009L, 2012L, 2011L, 
2013L, 2014L, 2012L, 2009L, 2014L, 2013L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 
2012L, 2013L, 2011L, 2014L, 2011L, 2013L, 2012L, 2009L, 2010L, 
2011L, 2010L)), .Names = c("vnum1", "vnum2", "vint1", "vint2", 
"vyear"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -25L))
>
```

I am using above to get matrix of correlation coef and p values.

```
> cor <- rcorr(as.matrix(ddf), type="pearson")
> cor$r
      vnum1 vnum2 vint1 vint2 vyear
vnum1  1.00  0.05 -0.01  0.00 -0.09
vnum2  0.05  1.00 -0.01 -0.01  0.22
vint1 -0.01 -0.01  1.00 -0.37  0.17
vint2  0.00 -0.01 -0.37  1.00 -0.02
vyear -0.09  0.22  0.17 -0.02  1.00


> cor$P
      vnum1  vnum2  vint1  vint2  vyear 
vnum1        0.8290 0.9772 0.9999 0.6631
vnum2 0.8290        0.9729 0.9473 0.2980
vint1 0.9772 0.9729        0.0671 0.4030
vint2 0.9999 0.9473 0.0671        0.9057
vyear 0.6631 0.2980 0.4030 0.9057       
> 

> cor$n
      vnum1 vnum2 vint1 vint2 vyear
vnum1    25    25    25    25    25
vnum2    25    25    25    25    25
vint1    25    25    25    25    25
vint2    25    25    25    25    25
vyear    25    25    25    25    25
```

How can I combine these 2 matrices to get a data.frame with following columns:

```
var1    var2    r_value     p_value     N
vnum1   vnum1   1.00        NA          25
vnum1   vnum2   0.05        0.8290      25
vnum1   vint1   -0.01       0.9722      25
...
```

I tried:

```
outdf = data.frame(var1=character(), var2=character(), r_value=numeric(), p_value=numeric(), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
outdf[,1:2] = expand.grid(colnames(df), colnames(df))
outdf$r_value = cor$r[outdf$var1, outdf$var2]
outdf
```

But it does not work. Thanks for your help.

Edit: it should also take care of missing values (NA).

Comment: The comment about missing value is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code works on your example:

```
varnames <- expand.grid( names(ddf), names(ddf) )
outdf <- data.frame( varnames, t(apply(varnames, 1, function(row) c(COR=cor$r[row[1], row[2]], PVAL=cor$P[row[1], row[2]],N=cor$n[row[1], row[2]]))))
```

Answer (score 3):

You may try:

```
library(reshape2)
lst1 <- setNames(list(cor$r, cor$P, cor$n), c("r_value", "P_value", "N"))
res <- dcast(melt(lst1),Var1+Var2~L1, value.var="value")
res$r_value <- round(res$r_value,2)
head(res,2)
#  Var1  Var2  N  P_value r_value
#1 vnum1 vnum1 25       NA    1.00
#2 vnum1 vnum2 25 0.828973    0.05
```

Or as suggested by @Ananda Mahto

```
res2 <- dcast(melt(unclass(cor)), Var1 + Var2 ~ L1)
```

and change the column names accordingly

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please add code for missing values (NA) also.

Comment: `dcast(melt(unclass(cor)), Var1 + Var2 ~ L1)` also gets you most of the way there. I don't think the `lapply(cor, as.matrix)` is really necessary (but +1).

Comment: @rnso Isn't it showing `NA` for the missing combinations?

Comment: @Ananda Mahto Thanks, I didn't think about `unclass`

Comment: I have got 3 great answers. Thanks everyone.